# Magento2.4 How to override \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart?

Tags: cart, magento2.4, preference

**Even if I simply copy the file without changes, it does not work as a preference. Any idea why?**

**I created a preference in di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" type="Mycompany\Myapp\Controller\Cart\Add" />
</config>
```

**I am simply trying to force adding a product to the cart with static data. The same code works in the core file "vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php", but does not work in "Mycompany/Myapp/Controller/Cart/Add.php". It causes the page to redirect to product 4.**

**Core File: works fine**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
 * Controller for processing add to cart action.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart
        );
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize product instance from request data
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|false
     */
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        
        $productId = (string)"4";
        
        
        if ($productId) {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
            )->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Your session has expired')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $paramsOrig = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        
        
        $params = [];
        $params['uenc'] = $paramsOrig['uenc'];
        $params['product']= "4";
        $params['selected_configurable_option'] = "";
        $params['related_product'] = "";
        $params['item'] = '4';
        $params['form_key'] = $paramsOrig['form_key'];
        $arr[2] = '3';
        $params['options'] = $arr;
        $params['qty'] = '1';

        
        
        
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /** Check product availability */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }
            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName()
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                        'addCartSuccessMessage',
                        [
                            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                            'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                        ]
                    );
                }
                if ($this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $errors = $this->cart->getQuote()->getErrors();
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getText());
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Resolve response
     *
     * @param string $backUrl
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     */
    protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            return parent::_goBack($backUrl);
        }

        $result = [];

        if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
            $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
        } else {
            if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
                $result['product'] = [
                    'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
        );

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Returns cart url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getCartUrl()
    {
        return $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * Is redirect should be performed after the product was added to cart.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function shouldRedirectToCart()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

**Preference File: Not Working!**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mycompany\Myapp\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
 * Controller for processing add to cart action.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart
        );
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize product instance from request data
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|false
     */
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        
        $productId = (string)"4";
        
        
        if ($productId) {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
            )->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Your session has expired')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $paramsOrig = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        
        
        $params = [];
        $params['uenc'] = $paramsOrig['uenc'];
        $params['product']= "4";
        $params['selected_configurable_option'] = "";
        $params['related_product'] = "";
        $params['item'] = '4';
        $params['form_key'] = $paramsOrig['form_key'];
        $arr[2] = '3';
        $params['options'] = $arr;
        $params['qty'] = '1';

        
        
        
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /** Check product availability */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }
            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName()
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                        'addCartSuccessMessage',
                        [
                            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                            'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                        ]
                    );
                }
                if ($this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $errors = $this->cart->getQuote()->getErrors();
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getText());
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Resolve response
     *
     * @param string $backUrl
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     */
    protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            return parent::_goBack($backUrl);
        }

        $result = [];

        if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
            $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
        } else {
            if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
                $result['product'] = [
                    'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
        );

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Returns cart url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getCartUrl()
    {
        return $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * Is redirect should be performed after the product was added to cart.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function shouldRedirectToCart()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the file location of the di.xml file? And why you added 4 into the code of your controller?

Comment: /etc/di.xml. The number 4 is a specific product that I am trying to add, but more importantly, if I copy and past the code (only changing the namespace), the preference fails. The location is fine and the script is runs, verified by writing to logs from within the file.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Cart\AddToCartUrl" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Cart**

**AddToCartUrl.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\RequestQuantityProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;

class AddToCartUrl extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var RequestQuantityProcessor
     */
    private $quantityProcessor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param RequestQuantityProcessor|null $quantityProcessor
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ? RequestQuantityProcessor $quantityProcessor = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart,
            $productRepository,
            $quantityProcessor
        );
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->quantityProcessor = $quantityProcessor ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(RequestQuantityProcessor::class);
    }

    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Your session has expired')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $this->quantityProcessor->prepareQuantity($params['qty']);
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /** Check product availability */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }
            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                        $product->getName()
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                        'addCartSuccessMessage',
                        [
                            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                            'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                        ]
                    );
                }
                if ($this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $errors = $this->cart->getQuote()->getErrors();
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getText());
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack($gobackurl, $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Returns cart URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getCartUrl()
    {
        return $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * Is redirect should be performed after the product was added to the cart.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function shouldRedirectToCart()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***